# How to run rails server with the rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning rails api, and below is my rails routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do 
    resources :posts, only: [:index, :show] 
  end

end
```

when i tried to run the server with

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/1
```

it gives me the error `no routes matches`, but It works with the below

```
http://api.lvh.me:3000/posts/1
```

what is the difference between two and how does it works.It is a way to run the server with default localhost:3000 when using the api

rake routes

```
       Prefix Verb URI Pattern             Controller#Action

 api_posts GET  /posts(.:format)     api/posts#index {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
 api_post GET  /posts/:id(.:format)     api/posts#show {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }

This is stating that this route is only present for requests that originate from the specified subdomain.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

To expand on my answer, I will ask you if the API is a component of a larger Rails application?  If not, the constraint is unneeded as you can take of this via DNS settings through you domain hosting service.

Comment: @tagCliny thanks It worked. I am just learning rails api so its not a big issue for me.